# Where does the fourth step come from?

Tags: operations-research

[image: The solution]

I'm talking about the step after $x(x-1) = \sqrt\frac{\mu}{3}$.

Comment: Quadratic formula : To solve for $x$ get a quadratic equation out of what is given and solve it.

Comment: Taking square root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$x(x-1)=\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{3}}$$

$$x^2-x-\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{3}}=0$$

Now [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) gives

$$(x-\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{1}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{3}}$$

so $$x=\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\sqrt{\mu/3}+\frac{1}{4}}$$

Then since you want the solution with $x>1$, you take the positive root and hence
$$x=\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\sqrt{\mu/3}+\frac{1}{4}}.$$

Comment: Oh wow... I'm so ashamed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This step follows after the resolution of the [quadratic equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation)

$$x(x-1) = \sqrt\frac{\mu}{3} \iff x^2-x-\sqrt\frac{\mu}{3}=0$$

with the condition $x\ge1$.